# ARM assembly dereferencing string only retrieving 4 bytes

Tags: string, assembly, memory, arm

I have the following code in my ARM assembly program

```
.data

.balign 4
prompt1: .asciz "Enter a string: "

.balign 4
scan1: .asciz "%s"

.balign 4
string_read: .word 0

.text

.global main

main:
  push {fp, lr}
  ldr r0, addr_prompt1
  bl printf

  ldr r0, addr_scan1
  ldr r1, addr_string_arg
  bl scanf

  ldr r2, addr_string_arg
  ldr r2, [r2]



addr_prompt1 : .word prompt1
addr_scan1 : .word scan1
addr_string_arg : .word string_read
```

I am using GDB PEDA to debug. Let us say that I input "test_cases" as my string. I can see that when I perform

```
ldr r2, addr_string_arg
```

it is holding an address that is pointing to the full string "test_cases".
However, after I dereference

```
ldr r2, [r2]
```

r2 now holds the value (b'test'). When I try passing this to a function, it becomes "test/002". This happens with any string that is more than 4 characters long. I tried changing the values next to .balign as well as .word and neither of those helped.

Comment: `r2` is 32 bit register... you can put only "so much" information into 32 bits... In case of 8 bit letter encoding, like ASCII, 32 bits can hold 4 letters. (in case of variable-length encoding like UTF8 the 32 bit register can hold from "part" to four letters (IIRC the longest point-code of UTF8 is 6 bytes = 48 bits needed)

Comment: @Ped7g is there any way for me to read the characters in a different format such that each character would be only a single byte, allowing me to fit a 32 character string?

Comment: strings are passed by reference, with the *address* in a register, not the contents.  Use `ldr r0, =scan1` to put the address in a register.  (The assembler will transparently do something like what you're doing now; loading the address from a nearby literal pool).

Comment: The ASCII encoding is like that, one character = one byte (ASCII is 7 bits encoding, but practically it is almost always padded to be 8 bits). But register is 32 bits, not bytes. One bit is just two states: 0 or 1. Eight bits are one byte, that allows for 2^8 = 256 distinct states/patterns (bit patterns from 00000000 to 11111111). ARM registers are 32 bits, that allows for 2^32 distinct states/patterns (that's enough for four concatenated bytes). But most of the APIs (like `printf`) take "string" data as memory address (pointer) of first character of string, not the character themselves.

Comment: And they usually expect "C string", i.e. the last ("hidden") character is zero terminator, which tells the `printf` implementation where the string ends. Some other API may resolve that differently, like for example POSIX `write` expects memory address of first byte of data to be written AND length of data to be written, but it does not check the content (i.e. you can write also data containing zero). But something like `puts` is unable to print zero byte as character (as it can print only C string, and C string can't contain zero as "visible" character).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the comments under your question are relevant, but nobody's posted an actual *answer* yet, so here goes!

Strings are, by their nature, variable in length.  For this reason they are almost invariably stored in memory, and passed around using a pointer to the first character.  Also by convention (at least in the C world, and you're interacting with C libraries in your code) the length of the string is not stored anywhere, the end of the string being instead marked by a zero byte.

You're actually using strings in the correct conventional way in several places in your code - when you obtain the address of `addr_prompt` to pass as the first argument to `printf`, for example.  When you use the instruction

```
ldr r2, addr_string_arg
```

you are loading the address of the first character of the string argument into `r2`, and it would be standard practice to use that address to represent the string.  When you subsequently write

```
ldr r2, [r2]
```

you are effectively dereferencing the pointer and loading four bytes (32 bits) starting from that address into `r2`. `r2` doesn't contain the string, just the first four bytes of it; and indeed those bytes may not even be in the same order as they were in memory, depending on the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your system.

Note also that you must allocate enough storage space to hold the longest string you could ever expect, and at the moment you are not doing so (`string_read` is only 4 bytes, which with the termination character allows for a three-character string).  Allowing the string to overflow its buffer leads to undefined behaviour.

As an aside, when you're loading arbitrary constants (including addresses) into registers the '`LDR` pseudo-instruction' is what you want - and this uses an equals sign before the second argument.  This could assemble into more than one instruction, depending on the constant to be loaded; for nearby addresses it's often implemented as a PC-relative `ADD`, but you don't need to care about that when you use it.  For example,

```
ldr r2, =string_read
```

removes the need for your `addr_string_arg`.